# Multiplication of values from two different table columns does not work if table data is retrieved from a JSON file (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have created a page where I have static data. I have an input box in one column. Then I have a function that multiplies the value I put in this input box to a number of another column. The result is working and it is shown below :

```js
$(function() {
       $("input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           $("tr").each(function () {
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
      var $val2 = $('.odds', this).text();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1
               $('.multTotal',this).text($total.toPrecision(3));
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }
    
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
max-width:50px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
            <th>NUMBER 1</th>
            <th>NUMBER 2</th>
   <th>RESULT</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td class="stake"><input class="val1"/></td>
            <td class="odds">2.2</td>
   <td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td class="stake"><input class="val1"/></td>
            <td class="odds">2.2</td>
   <td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

Now I am trying to retrieve the table data from a JSON file (url) and then multiply the cell values. I created a snippet below but the JSON data does not load here probably due to the fact that the url is an https. So please check the [LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/stack.html) instead. You can easily see the code in the snippet too.

```js
$.getJSON(
     'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
     function(data){
         var tr;
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td class="stake"><input class="val1"/>' + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="odds">' + val.id + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });
       });

$(function() {
       $("input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           $("tr").each(function () {
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.odds', this).text();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1
               $('.multTotal',this).text($total.toPrecision(3));
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }
    
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
max-width:50px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
   <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
    <th>A3</th>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Try to close the tr tag : $('<tr id="Memory1" class="part_detail txtMult"></tr>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding multiple elements (trs) with the same ID ("Memory1") which is invalid. Depending on what the "scripts for the filters and the multiply function" actually do, that *might* be the cause.

EDIT: Based on the link you provided, this is what's happening:

1. js/multiply_cells script is saying "attach an event to all matching INPUTs"
2. An AJAX request is updating the page, adding INPUTs

You don't want those things to happen in that order. Either call the first bit of code after you've added the INPUTs to the DOM, or look into [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

The former is a *bit* simpler; try something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json', function(data) {
    var tr;

    $.each (data, function (key, val) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append('<td class="stake"><input class="val1"/>' + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td class="odds">' + val.id + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
        $('table').append(tr);
    });

    $("input").keyup(multInputs);
});

function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;

    $("tr").each(function () {
        var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.odds', this).text();
        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1
        $('.multTotal', this).text($total.toPrecision(3));
        mult += $total;
    });

    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
}
```

Comment: It should work then for the Memory1 ID. Even with that :    `$.getJSON(
         'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
         function(data){
             var tr;
       var i=1;
             $.each (data, function (key, val) {
               ...
                $('table').append(tr);
       i++;
             });
           });`

it did not work.

Comment: Have you inspected the markup using the console, once the JSON call has done its thing? Does it look as intended? Do the "scripts for the filters" take into account that the DOM will change (i.e. it's not set up on initial page load)?

Comment: As a first step. I am trying to make the multiply function work. I created the query and called in the header of the HTML file. The other one with the filters might be more complex. I made everything work and then I started working on the JSON retrieval. I did not expect it to be difficult. Isn't possible to make it work?

Comment: If the code you have provided is working as expected, please provide the code that isn't - e.g. the "scripts for the filters"

Comment: I haven't. I was updating the question once again to make it way simpler. I excluded some scenarios. It has nothing to do with the tr ids or classes. I created a new link where I load the JSON data but also keep some static data in the table. It works for the static data (first two rows) but not for the rest of them. The link is the same as the one I put in the question. It only has to change in the end to : /TEB/NOT.html

Comment: where did you see this : "attach an event to all matching INPUTs" ? I was not getting any error in the console.

Comment: The statement `$("input").keyup(multInputs);` means 'find all INPUT elements, attach the function `multInputs` as a handler for the `keyup` event'. The 'search' for all INPUT elements takes place *at that moment in time*, so it needs to occur *after* the INPUT elements have been added to the DOM.

Comment: I see. Can I alter the script and make it work without the current keyup event? If not, how can I make sure that the search will start after the elements are added to the dom?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer see edit - try that and let me know how it goes

Comment: It worked :) Thanks a lot. I will now try to replicate a filter for min-max values (link ends in NOT2.html). I will raise another ticket for that soon. Cheers